# Mixed partial derivative subscript notation order

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a question regarding the order in which the mixed partial derivative notation is to be interpreted. The definition in some of my books conflicts with the others. In particular,
Does:
$$f_{xy} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}$$
or
$$f_{xy} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}$$

Some books like "Advanced Engineering Mathematics" by Erwin Kreyszig follow the 1st notation, while many books by Indian authors and the material taught to us in Bachelor's follow the 2nd notation.

[image]

The above is the one followed by Erwin Kreyszig in "Advanced Engineering Mathematics". But, most Indian authors and teachers follow the notation below (followed in "Differential Calculus" by Das and Mukerjee)

[image]

Why are they different(for the mixed partial derivatives)?

Comment: For most functions relevant in engineering the order does not matter because of the [Theorem of Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Theorem_of_Schwarz).

Comment: @KurtG. We have some questions in our Math - I course where we need to prove $f_{xy}\neq f_{yx}$ There the order would matter right? But I just got confused in the notations, since different books followed different notations